# How to avoid reCAPTCHA verification while using firebase phone auth in react native app?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api

The SafetyNet Api is disable and now we need to integrate Google Play Integrity API but not sure how to do it in React native app to avoid reCAPTCHA verification.

Tried steps mention in react-native-firebase/app-check but that didn't work.